# Java Stack Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, generics, stack, classcastexception

I have to write a program that reads a postfix expression from the keyboard and store it in a stack. I keep getting a class cast exception at case "+" : and I can not figure it out. Is anyone able to help me?

```
    String option = (String)stack.pop();
    while( stack  != null )
    {
        switch( option )
        {
        case "+":

            int left = (Integer)stack.pop();
            int right = (Integer)stack.pop();
            int result = left + right;
            String temp = (String) stack.pop();
            stack.push(result);

            break;
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: You need to add the stack trace to your question. We cannot tell you what the problem is until we can see exactly the error and line reference.

Comment: I'm guessing that `int left = (Integer)stack.pop();` is the source of the first class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're popping stuff off your stack without checking what they are. This is almost certainly going to cause you trouble. How did you build your stack in the first place? Do you KNOW you've been doing something like:

```
stack.push("string that becomes temp");
stack.push(new Integer(5));
stack.push(new Integer(3));
stack.push("+")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to read a series of string inputs from your stack and convert the numeric ones using casting when you need to use conversion.

Assuming your users have caused some stack pushes like this

```
stack.push("1234");
stack.push("1");
stack.push("+");
```

The pop routine would look like this:

```
int left = Integer.parseint(stack.pop());
int right = Integer.parseint(stack.pop());
int result = left + right;
```

Casting is for when the object IS of the type you want. Conversion is for when you want it to become the right type.

I would also make your stack generic of type String to avoid doubt:

```
Stack<String> stack = new ....;
```

Comment: `Integer.parseint` takes a string and returns an integer. If the stack is of no type, then you'd either have to do a `toString()` on the return from the `pop()` function or a cast - `(String)`. I suggested the stack have a type - `Stack<String>`